# MongoDb sum aggregate C++

Tags: c++, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I want to translate the following shell script(MongoDB shell version: 2.6.1) to C++ language

```
db.account.aggregate([{$group: { _id:null, totalAmount: { $sum: "$amount" },count: { $sum: 1 }}}])
```

I have try the following code:

```
     void test1(mongo::DBClientConnection& c)
     {
       BSONObj res;

       BSONArray pipeline = BSON_ARRAY( 
                    BSON( "$group" << 
                         BSON( "_id" << "null" ) << 
                         BSON( "totalAmount" << BSON( "$sum" << "$amount" ))<<
                         BSON( "count" << BSON( "$sum" << 1 ))
                        )
                  );

       c.runCommand("test",BSON("aggregate" << "account" << "pipeline" << pipeline ),res);

       cout << res.toString() << endl;
     }
```

Above code would cause the compiler error!

```
     void test2(mongo::DBClientConnection& c)
     {
       BSONObj res;

       vector<BSONObj> pipeline;   
       pipeline.push_back( BSON( "$group" << BSON( "_id" << "null" ) ) );
       pipeline.push_back( BSON( "totalAmount" <<  BSON( "$sum" <<  "$amount" )) );

       c.runCommand( "test", BSON( "aggregate" << "account" << "pipeline" << pipeline ), res);

       cout << collection1<<res.toString() << endl;
     }
```

Above code would cause the run time error!

Anyone can help me ? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

umm..
When I was executed, This code is working successfully. 
I have a proof shot, but "Stack overflow Answer" isn't allowed me to upload pictures.:(

I guess it's slight syntax error. Is your sum added to be inside the group? check your code.

The following is my test code:

[code]

```
DBClientConnection c;
BSONObj res;

vector<BSONObj> pipeline;   
c.connect("127.0.0.1:27017");
pipeline.push_back( BSON( "$group" << BSON( "_id" << "null" << "totalAmount" <<  BSON( "$sum" <<  "$amount" ))));

c.runCommand( "security", BSON( "aggregate" << "nac" << "pipeline" << pipeline ), res);

cout << "Succeed!!!" << endl;
cout << "collection1: " << res.jsonString() << endl;

return 0;
```

[Execute]

~/bin]$ ./test.exe

Succeed!!!

collection1: {result: [{_id: "null", totalAmount: 426 } ], ok: 1.0 }

~/bin]$

Comment: This Code was work perfectly! But [ BSONArray pipeline = BSON_ARRAY( ... );] would caused the run time error! Thank you very much for your great help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not good at english, but I can help you.

1)

```
void test1(mongo::DBClientConnection& c)
 {
   BSONObj res;

   BSONArray pipeline = BSON_ARRAY( 
                BSONArray pipeline = BSON_ARRAY( 
                BSON( "$group" << 
                     BSON( "_id" << "null" << "totalAmount" << BSON( "$sum" << "$amount" ))<< "count" << BSON( "$sum" << 1 )
                    )
              );

   c.runCommand("test",BSON("aggregate" << "account" << "pipeline" << pipeline ),res);

   cout << res.toString() << endl;
 }
```

2)

```
void test2(mongo::DBClientConnection& c)
 {
   BSONObj res;

   vector<BSONObj> pipeline;   
   pipeline.push_back( BSON( "$group" << BSON( "_id" << "null" << "totalAmount" <<  BSON( "$sum" <<  "$amount" ))));

   c.runCommand( "test", BSON( "aggregate" << "account" << "pipeline" << pipeline ), res);

   cout << collection1<<res.toString() << endl;
 }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! The above code would also cause the run time error. The error message as following :

2014-09-18T13:37:49.034+0800 Assertion failure p src/mongo/client/dbclientinterface.h 1283
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'mongo::AssertionException'
what():  assertion src/mongo/client/dbclientinterface.h:1283
Aborted

Comment: Maybe c parameter(DBClientConnection) is not called connect().
add code: c.connect("127.0.0.1":27017");

Comment: Thank you! You are right!! But it still show the message as following :

{ errmsg: "exception: A pipeline stage specification object must contain exactly one field.", code: 16435, ok: 0.0 }